# How to get row numbers and select specific row using mySQL in GCP?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Platform with mySQL.

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
idUser, Name, timestamp
me@you.com, Mike Jones, 1-6-1900 05:00
us@we.com, Steve Brown, 1-2-1900 06:00
jsmith@email.com, John Smith, 1-5-1900 06:00
test@me.com, Sarah Lee, 1-3-1900 05:30
```

I want to make a query where I can say "find what row number jsmith@email.com is in", based on timestamp as the order/sort.

I have been able to get part of it working, I can generate some results showing row numbers based on the timestamp:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
ORDER BY timestamp
```

This gets me results with row numbers added:

```
row_num, idUser, Name, timestamp
1,us@we.com, Steve Brown, 1-2-1900 06:00
2,test@me.com, Sarah Lee, 1-3-1900 05:30
3,jsmith@email.com, John Smith, 1-5-1900 06:00
4,me@you.com, Mike Jones, 1-6-1900 05:00
```

I'd think I now would want to make that nested and use something like:

```
SELECT * from
(SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
ORDER BY timestamp)
WHERE idUser = 'jsmith@email.com'
```

But I get an error that the syntax is wrong.
I also tried making the first block of code a stored procedure, and then calling that, but I can't seem to use that with SELECT either.

So back to my original question, I'd like it to report back to me he is in row #3

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge and Raymond, that got me in the right direction. I have it setup now as a stored procedure I can call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from
(SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
ORDER BY timestamp)
WHERE idUser = 'jsmith@email.com'
```

Needs a have a rewrite into

```
SELECT * from (
   SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number:= 0) AS init
ORDER BY timestamp) AS alias 
WHERE idUser = 'jsmith@email.com'
```

Or as comma based CROSS JOIN.

```
SELECT * from (
      SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
    , (SELECT @row_number:= 0) AS init
ORDER BY timestamp) AS alias 
WHERE idUser = 'jsmith@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  table name alias  `FROM ( )  t`

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT t.* from   (
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,idUser FROM SpeakerQueueActive
ORDER BY timestamp) t  /* here add the table name alias */
WHERE t.idUser = 'jsmith@email.com'
```

Comment: `SET @row_number:=0;` is not correct syntax also atleast not when used in a select like that.